# Mysql Explain shows that query is using index when it shouldnt be according to Mysql doc

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I created a mysql multi column index on a transactions table. This index uses 3 columns as described in my rails schema :

```
  add_index "merchant_transactions", ["reference", "parent_ref", "kind"], name: "by_reference_parent_ref_kind", using: :btree
```

Now I have this active record query :

```
MerchantTransaction.where(reference: "2-9020", kind: "PLACE_BATCH")
```

which in pure sql gives :

```
"SELECT `merchant_transactions`.* FROM `merchant_transactions` WHERE `merchant_transactions`.`reference` = '2-9020' AND `merchant_transactions`.`kind` = 'PLACE_BATCH'"
```

Now from what I read about mysql and multi column indexing :

> If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the
>   index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows. For example, if
>   you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed
>   search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).
>   For more information, [see Section 8.3.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html), “Multiple-Column
>   Indexes”.

To me, this means that the precedent query shouldnt be using the previous index.

However when I run EXPLAIN on my query `MerchantTransaction.where(reference: "2-9020", kind: "PLACE_BATCH").explain` under the `key`column, I get `by_reference_parent_ref_kind` and under the `Extra` column I have  `Using index condition` which seems to imply that the index is actually used.

How is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will use the index as you have the leftmost column listed in query (`reference`), i.e use case (col1) from docs. The other column in condition (`kind`) is not searched through the index.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
WHERE reference = '...' AND kind = '...'
```

and

```
INDEX(reference, parent, kind)
```

The optimizer can use the index, but only the `reference` part.

On the other hand, if the only columns mentioned in the query are those three, then that index is "covering", so the Optimizer has another reason to use that index.

Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.  In the `Key_len` column it will hint that only `reference` is used.  In the `Extra` column, `Using index` is the clue that it is "covering".

This would be a better index for the current query, but might be worse for some other query:

```
INDEX(reference, kind, parent)
```